# Pivotal Cloud Foundry - Cell and Garden

Tags: cloud-foundry

1. When PCF is installed on IAAS , does it get installed on multiple
   VMs which are denoted as cells by PCF?
2. Will each cell contain a garden implementation?
3. Will all cells all the different implementations of garden (windows , linux and docker)?
4. Can a single cell have both windows and linux based apps running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of these questions are not entirely clear, but I'll try my best to answer them.

> 1. When PCF is installed on IAAS , does it get installed on multiple VMs which are denoted as cells by PCF?

Yes, Cloud Foundry comprises multiple VMs.  The VMs are deployed and managed by Bosh (or Ops Manager & Bosh, if you're using Pivotal Cloud Foundry).

This is not an exhaustive list, but you'll see VMs for jobs like the Cloud Controller, UAA, Doppler, Traffic Controller and, of course, your Diego Cells.

The Diego Cells are where your applications run though, so you will typically have more Cells than any other VM type.

> 2. Will each cell contain a garden implementation?

Yes.  Garden Linux (called [Guardian](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/guardian)) on your Linux Cells & [Garden Windows](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/garden-windows) for Windows Cells.

> 3. Will all cells all the different implementations of garden (windows , linux and docker)?

No.  Linux Cells run Linux based apps (most of the build packs and Docker) and Windows Cells run Windows apps (HWC build pack).

> 4. Can a single cell have both windows and linux based apps running?

No, unless you want to count the fact that you can run .NET Core apps on Linux.  That's a little different though.

If you want to deploy both Linux & Windows apps, you'll need to have at least two Cells.  One for Linux & one for Windows.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much . These are very helpful . How does one define how many cells should be Linux vs windows ? Can this be done using Ops Manager ?

Comment: You would scale based on your need.  Each cell will have a finite amount of memory, disk and CPU.  As you deploy applications to PCF, your applications will consume those resources.  Typically you would monitor your platform, there are metrics to show resources consumed and remaining, and when you hit certain levels scale up or down your Cell count.  If you don't monitor, you'll eventually see Insufficient Resources as your Cells run out of resources.  You could use that as a cue to scale your Cells up too.

Comment: Thanks Daniel , how could make a cell as Linux cell or Windows cell ?

Answer (score 1):

@punter-vicky - Initially, if you run `cf stacks` you will see output like:

```
name         description
cflinuxfs2   Cloud Foundry Linux-based filesystem
```

The [Using PCF Runtime for Windows](http://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-12/windows/index.html) portion of Pivotal's documentation gives a complete overview of how to install and use Windows cells.

Once you have both types of cells available, the first priority Diego considers in granting a winning auction bid is whether the cell offers the correct stack for the application being bid on.